# Having trouble with making database show

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

New to coding and working on a project. I can't figure out why my code isn't showing on my page. I can use all the advice you'd like to give! I know I have an error in my code that's most likely preventing it but I can't seem to pin it down. thanks! In my other pages, the data populates perfectly fine. I'm trying to make a form select option for categories but none of the categories are populating in the drop down box.

'''

```
  @Controller
   public class Products {
      @Autowired
        private ProductService pService;
      @Autowired
       private CategoryService cService;

@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model viewModel) {
    return "index.jsp";
}
@GetMapping("/products")
public String showProducts(Model viewModel) {
    List<Product> allProducts=this.pService.getAllProducts();
    viewModel.addAttribute("products", allProducts);
    return "allProducts.jsp";
}
@GetMapping("/new/product")
public String addProduct(Model viewModel,@ModelAttribute("product")Product product) {
    List<Category> allCategories=this.cService.getAllCategories();
    viewModel.addAttribute("allCategories",allCategories);
    return "createProduct.jsp";
}
@PostMapping("/new/product")
public String newProduct(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product")Product product, BindingResult result, Model viewModel) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        List<Category> allCategories=this.cService.getAllCategories();
        viewModel.addAttribute("allCategories",allCategories);
        return "createProduct.jsp";
    }
    this.pService.createProduct(product);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

'''

/new/product.jsp
'''

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
      <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
     <title>Insert title here</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
<h1>Add new product!</h1>
<form:form methods="POST" action="/new/product" modelAttribute="product">
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:select path="categories">
        <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">
        <option value="${category.id}">${category.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:label path="name">Name</form:label>
        <form:errors path="name"/>
        <form:input path="name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:label path="description">Description</form:label>
        <form:errors path="description"/>
        <form:input path="description"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:label path="price">Price</form:label>
        <form:errors path="price"/>
        <form:input path="price"/>
    </div>
    <button>Add New Product!</button>

</form:form>
   </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: no, sorry. the JSP shown is at /new/product

Comment: So, change `items="${categories}"` to `items="${allCategories}"`.

Comment: lol, that worked!! thanks so much